# Create contacts in Sitecore 7.2

Tags: experience-analytics, dms

In our project, we are creating users instead of contacts in Sitecore to track users interaction. For that, we need to log in that user in Sitecore first. 
Can we create contacts instead of users in Sitecore 7.2?

Comment: I'm quite sure the Contact was not implemented till 7.5 (which you shouldn't use) and properly implemented in 8+
You can do some of the same things with Visitor, but not nearly to the same extent.
You don't need a user to login, you can create and login virtual users (for instance based on a cookie). But if it's for tracking and personalization, I would recommend updating to a newer Sitecore

Comment: If you'd like to have proper contact interaction tracking, you really should upgrade past 7.2. The DMS implementation back then did not scale well. The cost of implementing that functionality correctly and with performance might actually be less than upgrading and just using built-in functionality in a later version, depending on what your upgrade path looks like.

Answer (score 1):

Sitecore contacts were introduced in 7.5 together with xDb.

Before Sitecore 7.5 it was Sitecore DMS and Sitecore OMS.

Many people were not happy with Sitecore DMS.

I suggest you to upgrade to new releases of Sitecore (releases 8+) rather than try to implement on Sitecore 7.2.

Mainstream Support of Sitecore 7.2 ended in Dec 2017 and you have one more reason to upgrade to new releases.

Comment: "Many people were not happy with Sitecore DMS" is unsubstantiated. Secondly; OP asks how to best work with the concept of "Contacts" in the context of 7.2 - asking OP to upgrade is not an answer to the question.